# Disable ESET NOD32 v9 SSL email traffic certificate

Tags: email, thunderbird, ssl, anti-virus, certificate

I am using a self-generated certificate for my mail server to which I connect through SSL/TLS. Due to the self-generated certificate which I have not added to the Windows certificate store, Thunderbird asks me to add an exception for this certificate in order to use it. So far, things went fine for years.

Today, Thunderbird presented me a dialog to add an exception for my email certificate. Of course I was surprised and looked into the certificate details. It shows "ESET SSL Filter CA" in the chain, which is a clear indicator that this change is related to the upgrade of ESET NOD32 virus scanner to version 9 I performed yesterday.

A [similar question for Avast](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73476/why-is-avast-web-mail-shield-root-listed-as-ca-for-google-com) suggests that

- this is not much of an issue, since the man in the middle here is an anti virus software that I trust.
- one could turn off that feature to get the old behavior back

So that's what I did: disable the email protocol check. Unfortunately this does not help, even after a reboot:

[image: Email check turned off]

How do I get rid of ESETs certificate? (Uninstalling is not an option)

Comment: @Ramhound: I wondered what that would help and here it is: that makes the certificate untrusted, but ESET still uses it of course

Answer (score 0):

There is a second option in the "WEB UND E-MAIL" category which can be used to disable TLS/SSL protocol filtering.

I experienced the same problem, and deactivating protocol filtering here helped.

However I guess that this also disables NOD32 scanning of incoming email for viruses.

I contacted ESET support and asked for information about the effect of disabling protocol filtering. Their answer was to visit the page http://support.eset.com/kb2138/?viewlocale=de_DE (which does not cover this specific question).

Comment: If I do this, ESET turns red, Thunderbird still displays the dialog and it crashes when I click the accept button. It's so annoying...